# Nested DTOs with optional navigation properties: "No coercion operator is defined between types 'Expression[]' and anonymous type"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

Im am trying to build a nested DTO with Entity Framework (6.2.0) using navigation properties. The navigation properties are optional, so I need to handle null values in a way that the corresponding property of the DTO is null also:

```
var result = db.Projects.Select(
    p => new
    {
        p.Id,
        Notifications = p.Notifications
            .Where(n => n.ContactId == user.Id)
            .Select(a => new
            {
                a.Id,
                a.ContactId,
                Candidate = a.Candidate == null ? null : new
                {
                    a.Candidate.Id,
                    a.Candidate.LastName
                }
            })
            .OrderByDescending(n => n.Timestamp)

    })
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == projectId);
```

As the code shows, in my model, there are `Project` entities with 0-n `Notifications`, where a `Notification` can *optionally* have one `Candidate`.

The above code throws:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No coercion operator is defined
> between types 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[]' and
> '<>f__AnonymousType43`2[System.Int32,System.String]'.'

at runtime. If I remove the null check like so

```
Candidate = new
{
   a.Candidate.Id,
   a.Candidate.LastName
}
```

it expectedly throws an exception when the `Candidate` property is null. Null propagation does not work either, and - even if it did - would not meet the requirement that the DTO property `Candidate` should be null and not an object with null property values:

```
Candidate = new
{
   Id = a.Candidate?.Id,
   LastName = a.Candidate?.LastName
}
```

This does not compile:

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

- How can I create a nested DTO with optional properties based on (optional) navigation properties?
- What is considered best practice for this (not so exotic?) requirement?

For reference, the definition of the navigation properties:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(entity =>
{
    // ...

    entity.HasMany(p => p.Notifications)
        .WithOne(a => a.Project)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ProjectId)
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

});

modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>(entity =>
{  
    // ...
 
    entity.HasOne(e => e.Candidate)
        .WithMany(c => c.Notifications)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.CandidateId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Guid)
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
});
```

Comment: Are yo using strings or some other type?  String should automatically handle nulls.

Comment: @jdweng `Candidate` is a navigation property: It's of type `Candidate`, a entity type of my model.

Comment: Are Id and Name strings?

Comment: @jdweng Id is int, Name is string. But the example is shortened, in my real life case, there are also Guids and bools.

Comment: Which properties are null?  I wouldn't expect a Guids to be null.

Comment: @jdweng The navigation properties are/can be null. I added their configuration to the question for reference. I am talking about optional foreign key relationships on the SQL side which get translated into object relationships by EF, see docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Comment: The error is due to the EDMX mapping file that is used by entity.  The mapping needs to be refreshed.  How did you create the mapping file?

Comment: I'm using code first... I don't have an EDMX file @jdweng

Comment: How are you getting the mapping? : https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#configuring-or-mapping-relationships

Comment: @jdweng sorry, i dont know what you mean. Im using EF code first, configured the relationships as shown in the question and migrated everything to the database. I don't deal with mappings manually.

Comment: There is something wrong with the mapping.  Either you changed the c# classes or the database and did not refresh the mapping.  I recommend you create the mapping automatically from the database using code or using the VS tools.  I do not know how to create mapping using tools starting from the c# classes.